# Multiply std::chrono timepoint by a scalar

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono, scalar

How can one multiply a `chrono` `timepoint` by a scalar? It works for `duration`s, but `timepoint`s can't be multiplied by a scalar ("error: invalid operands to binary expression").

### Context:

I have some code that in real life will run for a long time. For testing purposes, I want to be able to speed it up by a factor, so everything happens similarly, but just in fast forward.

I thought of making my own `ScaledClock` class, that returns values from `chrono::steady_clock`, but with a scaling parameter that can be set to something greater than 1 to achieve a speed up. Here is some code:

```
steady_clock::time_point ScaledClock::now() {
    return steady_clock::now() * speedUp; // <--- error
}

void ScaledClock::sleep_for(steady_clock::duration duration) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration / speedUp);
}

void ScaledClock::sleep_until(steady_clock::time_point time) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(time / speedUp); // <--- error
}
```

If the speedUp is 2, for instance, then the program will always think that twice as much time has passed. It will also sleep for half as long. As long as I am disciplined about not using this class for all timing, I think it should work.

(Alternatively, if someone has a much better way of achieving this, I'd love to hear it).

---

Edit: copy of comment, because I think it is useful clarification:

en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point:

> Class template std::chrono::time_point represents a point in time. It
>   is implemented as if it stores a value of type Duration indicating the
>   time interval from the start of the Clock's epoch.

So I want all the times since the epoch doubled. If the epoch is not start of program execution, and my code happens to think that it is running in 4036, I'm not really bothered

Comment: You can't multiply a timepoint (a moment or an instant) by a scalar. What does it mean to multiply 6pm by three, for example?

Comment: Multiplying (or dividing) a specific point in time really makes no sense. If you have the date 2018-09-05 and time 13:14:53.0, what would multiplying it by e.g. 2 really mean? Advance it to the year 4036?

Comment: I had understood that timepoints represent the time that has elapsed since a given start time (probably the start of program execution). In this way, it should make sense to multiply it (i.e. twice as much time since the start point).

Comment: The time elapsed since some point in time is a *duration*. Scaling a duration makes sense. Scaling the point in time itself doesn't.

Comment: Here is what I am talking about: "Class template std::chrono::time_point represents a point in time. It is implemented as if it stores a value of type Duration indicating the time interval from the start of the Clock's epoch." (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point). So I want all the times since the epoch doubled. If the epoch is not start of program execution, and my code happens to think that it is running in 4036, I'm not really bothered

Comment: You can multiply duration from some point of time (much closer to now, than epoch though). An additional method of your ScaledClock 'start' can set that 'point of time' to now, then ScaledClock::now(0 can return real now + (real now - start point of time) * 2

Comment: @wtom Yes, I think that would work. It involves more storing and manipulating of timepoints than I was hoping for, but this does not really matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to store a starting point (now() e.g. at program start) and then determine the time passed since that starting point as a duration. You can then add this duration multiplied with your factor to the start point and return it as time point in your `ScaledClock::now()` function. Just like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

  auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

  sleep(1);

  auto actualNow = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  auto timePassed = actualNow - start;
  auto timePassedScaled = timePassed * 2.0;
  auto scaledNow = start + timePassedScaled;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course you can also use the start of the Epoch as start, if you really like to run your program in virtual far future.

Comment: Thanks. For a floating point scalar multiplication, this converts the timepoint to have a double representation. How do I prevent this, or get it back to a `steady_clock::timepoint`? This seems to work, but is cumbersome: `auto timePassedScaled = duration_cast<duration<steady_clock::rep, steady_clock::period> >(timePassed * 2.0);`

Comment: I think one should omit the ".0" in the multiplication.

Comment: Yes, but I actually want the freedom to use floating point numbers, like 2.5 (I am using a double variable, `speedUp`, rather than a hard coded number like `2.0`).